# Zend_Pdf and templated

Tags: zend-framework, pdf, pdf-generation, zend-pdf

I have problems creating a template for my pdf documents in Zend_Pdf. I've followed the guide provided at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.pages.html but it doesn't seem to work since no footer text or logo are visible at any page except the first.

This is a sample of my code: (Note; the MTP constant is just the recalculate from mm to points)

```
//Create pdf object
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

//Create the first page
$page = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);

/*HEADER*/
//insert logo at the top
$logo = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../document_root/images/logotype.png');
$page->drawImage($logo, 22*MTP,274*MTP, 62*MTP, 289*MTP); 

/*FOOTER*/
$footerStyle->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 10);
$page->setStyle($footerStyle);
$page->drawText('Footer text', 33*MTP, 20*MTP, 'ISO-8859-1');

//save the page to pdf->pages
$pdf->pages[0] = $page;

//save the page as a template
$template = $pdf->pages[0];

//create the next page from template
$page1 = new Zend_Pdf_Page($template);

//save the next page to pdf->pages
$pdf->pages[] = $page1;
```

Have I completely misunderstood how this "template function" work in Zend_Pdf? I know that Zend_Pdf lacks quite a number of features compaired to some of the external pdf-generators (like FPDF) but still, there must be some way to make a basic header/footer for all pages right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `clone` instead passing page as argument to a new page.

```
$page1 = clone $template;
```

or simply

```
$pdf->pages[] = clone $pdf->pages[0];
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work either. I get an error message that says "Message:Cloning Zend_Pdf_Page object using 'clone' keyword is not supported. Use 'new Zend_Pdf_Page($srcPage)' syntax".  

I've done a workaround where I've implemented a new "newPage" function. Everytime I call this function it creates a page and then calls two new functions (generatePdfHeader and generatePdfFooter) to generate the header and footer. the resulting page is returned and then I can continue use the regular Zend_Pdf functions.

Comment: The question is - **What version of ZF do you use?**. I just tested it on 1.11.6 just to be 100% sure, and with this version pages are cloned without any problems.

Comment: I use 1.10 so that might be the problem. Unfortunately I don't have time to upgrade and redo the pdf function right now, but there is time dedicated after the beta release for bug-fixes, re-factoring and streamlining. During that phase I'll definitely upgrade and test it again. Thank you for the help